# elasticache redis not responding to redis-cli commands

Tags: redis, amazon-elasticache

I have set up elasticache with redis and the host is rechable which I can confirm with telnet, when Redis commands are issued it does not return any result, either with ubuntu@ip-10-0-2-8:~$ redis-cli -h master.xxxxxx-xxxx.xxxxx.xxxx.cache.amazonaws.com -p 6379 INFO or [image: telnet] and very unfortunately AWS cant show you redis logs

Answer (score 5):

> The redis-cli client does not support SSL/TLS connections. To use the
>   redis-cli to access an ElastiCache for Redis node (cluster mode
>   disabled) with in-transit encryption, you can use the stunnel package
>   in your Linux-based clients. The stunnel command can create an SSL
>   tunnel to Redis nodes specified in the stunnel configuration. After
>   the tunnel is established, the redis-cli can be used to connect an
>   in-transit encryption enabled cluster node.

Source: [https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elasticache-connect-redis-node/)

So you can either use stunnel or disabling in-transit encryption.

Comment: moved here i think https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/in-transit-encryption.html

Answer (score 4):

It's actually simpler than that and you don't need to disable Encryption-at-transit as suggested. Just use the --tls option along with the command as shown in the picture.

redis-cli -h  --tls

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJU9O.jpg)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

You need to add firewall rule to allow other machine to access your `redis` server. I meant you need to enable firewall rule to allow 6379 port accessible from outside. Following article will will help you to do this.
Also please make sure redis is running on port 6379 or some other port.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/accessing-elasticache.html#access-from-outside-aws

Comment: The problem was actually enabling Encryption-at-transit for Elasticache cluster disabling that allowed me to access the cluster